# Blender add-on "3D Print Toolbox" and MeshLab

Tags: 3d-models, blender

Blender software has a nice mesh analysis add-on called ”3D Print Toolbox". It is making us give it a second look for our 3D printing workflow.

On the other hand, MeshLab is very nice to have mesh repair tools.

I see the errors in the Blender, and then I close the program. And then I open MeshLab and make the corrections. The goal is to produce the model with a 3D printer.

Is there a possibility to do the analysis in MeshLab as well? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meshlab has a bunch of tools for that under 'Filters', you'd need to read the documentation for specifics as your needs may vary from model to model.

But it's much the same as the Blender addon with the 'Cleaning and Repairing' options to merge vertices, close holes etc,.